# Can I patent a software I have researched?

Tags: trading

I have researched a software and also have surfed on the internet and came to know that no such software exists, So there can be a possibility that this can be patented, and as this is unique and I know unique things can be patented. But as this is a software so can this be patented. Should I refer an attorney for this. I told this to one of my friends, she stays in Sydney she suggested me to consult [cotters registered designs](http://www.cotters.com.au/registered-designs/) which are in Sydney. She said they have senior attorneys so they can help. Should I go with her suggestions or someone can suggest me a better company to go with.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Community of Knowledge. Community Netiquette requires members to follow a few common rules, one of which is to ask in a certain manner -- use a **M**inimum **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample of code, and to post also all data, that such **MCVE-experiment** needs to become Verifiable on other members' computing devices. Notwithstanding the MCVE rule is sometimes reported or punished by site administrators, so might want to review and re-articulate your question to meet the common rules. May inspire how to ask in stackoverflow.com/tags/algorithmic-trading/topusers

Answer (score 0):

### Short version: No.

Software is not meeting a typical patent requirements.

### Long version:

Patent protection is something heavily related to a business model. If there are reasons to spend heaps of time, money & efforts, the business-potential of the patent-licensing fees ought be orders of magnitude higher, than the lump-sum of all the patent-agenda administration in all national ( regional ) domains + the initial / applied research & development costs, such patent-protected intellectual property has already accrued ( and will continue to heavily accrue, as the business-licensing process is also not a cost-free, nor a perpetuum-mobile self-powered and self-driven flow of a fully automated work-flow, running without a single touch of a human-hand ).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Australia, then you need more Australian patent expertise than I can provide. Patents are *not* global -- they're country by country.

Firstly, "I have researched" is not the basis for moving forward. A patent is an invention, not an idea.

I'm in the US, so this applies only to US. There is such a thing as the Patent Cooperation Treaty, which centralizes some of the process of multi-country patenting, but you still end up going to each national patent office. Quite expensive.

In the US, much software was made unpatentable by the Supreme Court's 2014 *CLS Bank* case, but there are still software patents. What exactly is patentable subject matter now is a complicated question and I wouldn't presume to answer for yours.

In the US, you can expect a very long pendency before issuance, if you even make it. The PTO will reject it, your attorney will argue, they will reject it again, you have to pay again for two more go-rounds, etc. In any upcoming Substack article, I go through what Facebook went through in 2020, for one of their patents on applying a mask to your face in a photo based on what your friends are wearing and how happy you seem! I'm not making this up.